# The length of the set which will be covered by Brownian motion in a time $t$

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion

I have the following question in mind which I wanted to answer: what is the measure of the set which will be covered by a standard Brownian motion $B(t)$ in a time $t$? Call this random variable $M(t)$. I want to find $P(M(t)\leq x)$. Call the probability density of this $h(x)$.

What I thought was the following: Denote by $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ the probability densities of respectively $P(-\min_{0\leq s\leq t}B(s)\leq x)$ and $P(\max_{0\leq s\leq t}B(s)\leq x)$. Then we have that
$$h(y)=\int_0^{\infty}f(x)g(y-x)dx$$
if the minimum and maximum of Brownian motion are independent. I don't know if this is the case. If someone can help me with this, I would really appreciate.

Comment: The density and a reference to a paper deriving it can be found at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/599697/distribuation-max-min-of-brownian-motion

Comment: @muaddib : ah, this is very nice! Thank you.

Comment: The minimum and maximum of Brownian motion are not independent. Their joint law is known.

Comment: @Did Could you give a reference for their joint law?

Comment: ?? Did you even *look* at the page @muaddib indicated?

Comment: @Did yes I did, but not good enough it seems